# Can I generalize solving a system of equations (with np.linalg.solve) to three dimensional arrays (still with two unknowns)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, solver

I want to know if the following problem is generalizable to a three-dimensional array, and can be done via slicing, etc.:

Let's say I have an array, x, that is of size (n, 2). I set up a system of linear equations using values in the array and solve as follows:

```
import numpy as np
def solve(x):
        a_array = np.array([[16, -1], [-2, 1]])
        b = np.array([x[-3, 0] - 16*x[-2, 0] + 30*x[-1, 0], 1*x[-3, 0] - 2*x[-2, 0] - 0*x[-1, 0]])
        u = np.linalg.solve(a_array, b)

        c = np.array([x[-3, 1] - 16*x[-2, 1] + 30*x[-1, 1], 1*x[-3, 1] - 2*x[-2, 1] - 0*x[-1, 1]])
        v = np.linalg.solve(a_array, c)

        total_uv = np.column_stack((u, v))
        
        final_x = np.concatenate((x, total_uv))
    return final_x
```

Essentially, I solve a system of linear equations (with two variables) based on values in my x array to get (1,2) arrays of u and v. I then stack those together to get a total array of (2,2) and concatenate that array to my original x. I get a final_x array size of (n+2, 2) now, compared to the original x.

My question is: Let's say that the x I start with is now of size (m, n, 2). For each (n,2) array (of which there are m), I want to solve this system of equations to get my total_uv array. Then I concatenate each total_uv array to each (n,2) array (so along axis=1 now), so my final result is of size (m, n+2,2).

Is there a way to do this without using for loops (i.e. looping over all the (n, 2) arrays and doing the computation, storing it, and then concatenating)? Such as just with slice notation, or a more elegant way in general?

It seems like slicing the x array (to get variables b and c) via `x[:, -3, 0] + ...` doesn't actually work, because a_array is of a different size.

Clarification of solution for (m, n, 2):

```
def solve(x):
        m = x.shape[0]
        a_array = np.array([[16, -1], [-2, 1]])
        b = np.stack((x[:, -3, 0] - 16*x[:, -2, 0] + 30*x[:, -1, 0],
              1*x[:, -3, 0] - 2*x[:, -2, 0] - 0*x[:, -1, 0]), axis=1)
        u = np.linalg.solve(a_array[None, :, :], b)

        c = np.stack((x[:, -3, 0] - 16*x[:, -2, 0] + 30*x[:, -1, 0],
              1*x[:, -3, 0] - 2*x[:, -2, 0] - 0*x[:, -1, 0]), axis=1)
        v = np.linalg.solve(a_array[None, :, :], c)

        # Concatenation here:
        total_uv = np.column_stack((u, v))

        uv_reshaped = total_uv.reshape((m, 2, 2))

        final_x = np.concatenate((x, uv_reshaped), axis=1)
    return final_x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice notation to create the `b` and `c` vectors as two dimensional arrays:

```
b = np.stack((x[:, -3, 0] - 16*x[:, -2, 0] + 30*x[:, -1, 0],
              1*x[:, -3, 0] - 2*x[:, -2, 0] - 0*x[:, -1, 0]), axis=1)
```

Then you can add an extra (batch) dimension to `a_array` to use it with `np.linalg.solve`:

```
u = np.linalg.solve(a_array[None, ...], b)
```

By the way, since your coefficients seem to be similar for `b` and `c` you could do the same here, eliminating the need for two calls to `np.linalg.solve`:

```
bc = np.stack((x[:, -3] - 16*x[:, -2] + 30*x[:, -1],
               1*x[:, -3] - 2*x[:, -2] - 0*x[:, -1]), axis=2)
uv = np.linalg.solve(a_array[None, None, ...], bc)
```

Then you have two batch dimensions `(n, 2)` where the second represents u/v.

Comment: Just to clarify: Does the typed out solution in my edited post reflect what you were trying to say? That is, `u=np.linalg.solve(a_array[None, :, :], b)` is what you meant? Also, here, the size of u and v are going to be (m, 2), where m is the original m dimension in the (m, n, 2) input array. Without doing a for loop, can you get the u and v (2,2) array for each m (e.g. like in my original solution), and then concatenate that to each (n, 2) array, as in my edited solution?

Comment: @user6496380 What I wanted to say is that you don't even need two separate vectors `b` and `c` and so you can do it all in one go. See the end of my answer using `bc` and `uv`; `uv` is your solution then.